# Bash optional argument

Tags: shell, posix

can someone tell me if there is some way of how to check if optional argument is followed by string and if it is not then there will be error message.

My goal is to have something like ./nameofscript -a string

```
I=0

while getopts ":a:k" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    a ) I=1 
    string="$OPTARG"
```

So my goal is ...if user type ./nameofscript it will continue because no optional argument was passed...but if the user types ./nameofscript -a program has to be exited because there wasnt any string behind it. User has to type ./nameofscript -a string and if he doesnt then there will be error message saying: u have to type something blablabla...

So is there any solution of how to know if -a was typed/ if -a was typed and is followed by string.

Comment: How are you using `getopts`? Can you show your script? `getopts` can require arguments.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and add your script and specify what "doesn't work" means exactly?

Answer (score 1):

When option string begins with a colon (`":"`) then `getopts` ignores all errors.  So, just take out the leading colon.

Comment: I fixed it by adding another option for : to my getopts but there is one more thing i cant figure out. How to prevent user from typing same optional argument 2 times for example... ./nameofscript -a -a would lead to error because 1. no argument and 2. two same arguments were passed

Comment: @jerry : If you are facing a new problem, please create a new question on Stackoverflow, instead of asking it in a comment. After all, your new problem might be of interest to many SO users.